# How to parse sql result?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

End my sorrow.

I make an ajax request to this file.

I want to get all the posts from database. Then stylise these posts and display it to the user.

But I couldn't figure out how to parse these from js.

```
...
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//Iterate the rows
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    //todo
} 
...

//jsfile
...
var response = this.responseText; 
//get the response but how to parse ?
```

Comment: You haven't shown enough code.  What is the value of `response`?  If you don't know, `console.log()` it.  Otherwise, you're just asking us to *write hte code for you*, which is not what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: `But I couldn't figure out how to parse these from js.` Did you try `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From your Post, you sound like you want to send some Data obtained from your Database Transactions to the Requesting AJAX Script, right? If that is the case; you may have to do all the usual Processing of your DB Data and (if necessary) build them up as an Array or Object within your PHP File. Afterwards, you encode the resulting Data to JSON using `json_encode()` and then lastly push the JSON-Encoded Data back to the requesting AJAX Script. To illustrate; here (below) is a Mock example using bits & pieces of the Code you posted:

```
<?php

    // PERFORM SOME DATABASE TRANSACTIONS....
    $result    = $conn->query($sql);

    // IF YOU NEED TO BUILD-UP A SPECIAL DATA STRUCTURE TO MEET WITH 
    // THE NEEDS OF YOUR APP. YOU MIGHT DO THAT HERE.
    // WE CREATE AN ARBITRARY ARRAY: $payload TO HOLD THE ARBITRARY DATA...
    $payload   = [];

    // LOOP THROUGH THE RETURNED RESULT-SET / ROWS OF DATA
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
        // WE PRETEND FOR NOW THAT WE NEED CERTAIN VALUES FOR THE APP
        // THAT WILL BE CONSUMED BY THE REQUESTING AJAX SCRIPT
        // SO WE BUILD IT HERE:
        $tempData       = [];     //<== TEMPORARY ARRAY TO HOLD A COLLECTION 
        $tempData[]     = $row['firs_name'];
        $tempData[]     = $row['last_name'];
        $tempData[]     = $row['address'];
        $tempData[]     = $row['email'];
        $tempData[]     = $row['avatar'];
        $tempData[]     = $row['telephone'];

        // NOW PUSH THE COLLECTION OF RELEVANT DATA GATHERED 
        // FROM THE ITERATION INTO THE PAYLOAD VARIABLE: $payload
        $payload[]      = $tempData;
    } 

    // OK: WE HAVE OUR PAYLOAD, READY TO BE SENT BACK AS JSON...
    // SO WE NOW ENCODE THE PAYLOAD TO JSON DATA STRUCTURE.
    $jsonData           = json_encode($payload);


    // THAT'S ALMOST IT....
    // THE NEXT THING WOULD BE TO SHIP THESE DATA TO THE REQUESTING SCRIPT
    // WHICH WE SHALL DO HERE WITH A SIMPLY die() STATEMENT LIKE SO:
    die($jsonData);
```